# Code::Blocks fails to create and to find obj files. "No such file or directory"

Tags: c, compiler-errors, codeblocks, sdl-2

Running Code::Blocks 17.12 on Windows 10. I used the install with minGW.

I working on an SDL2 project with C. (project as in .cbp project). I've already compiled and run the program just fine. Then I added a second source file. I included it in the first with:

```
#include <vec2D.c>
```

it couldn't find the new file, and then I added the directory of the project itself to the search directories of the compiler and the linker, which worked.

Then it couldn't find the obj files. I checked that they were there, both of them, in the appropriate directory, which they were. I noticed the error said

```
 Development\Game\game.c -o obj\Release\game.o||No such file or directory|
                                              ||error: no input files|
```

and the obj folder is in the Game folder, alongside the source file. should "game.c" be there at the end? I think if it were looking in "Development\Game" and not "Development\Game\game.c" maybe it would find the obj files, but I don't know how to change that.

I also tried rebuilding the entire project from scratch in another directory to see if C::B fixed it by itself, this time it created vec2d.o and found it during compilation, but not game.o (!!!).

[folder contents, C::B project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvWeF.png)

space.cbp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<CodeBlocks_project_file>
  <FileVersion major="1" minor="6" />
  <Project>
    <Option title="Space" />
    <Option pch_mode="2" />
    <Option compiler="gcc" />
    <Build>
      <Target title="Release">
        <Option output="bin/Release/Space" prefix_auto="1" extension_auto="1" />
        <Option working_dir="../Space" />
        <Option object_output="obj/Release/" />
        <Option type="1" />
        <Option compiler="gcc" />
        <Compiler>
          <Add option="-O2" />
          <Add directory="C:/SDL/SDL2-2.0.9/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2" />
          <Add directory="C:/SDL/SDL2_image-2.0.4/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2" />
          <Add directory="C:/Users/Introscopia/Game Development/Space/" />
        </Compiler>
        <Linker>
          <Add option="-s" />
          <Add option="-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image" />
          <Add directory="C:/SDL/SDL2_image-2.0.4/i686-w64-mingw32/lib" />
          <Add directory="C:/SDL/SDL2-2.0.9/i686-w64-mingw32/lib" />
          <Add directory="C:/Users/Introscopia/Game Development/Space/" />
        </Linker>
      </Target>
    </Build>
    <Compiler>
      <Add option="-Wall" />
    </Compiler>
    <Unit filename="space.c">
      <Option compilerVar="CC" />
    </Unit>
    <Unit filename="vec2d.c">
      <Option compilerVar="CC" />
    </Unit>
    <Unit filename="vec2d.h">
      <Option compile="1" />
      <Option link="1" />
    </Unit>
    <Extensions>
      <code_completion />
      <envvars />
      <debugger />
      <lib_finder disable_auto="1" />
    </Extensions>
  </Project>
</CodeBlocks_project_file>
```

Comment: I don't know Code::Blocks specifically, but why are you `#include`ing .c files in the first place?

Comment: Is that not legal? I know convention is to use .h files, but I thought including .c also worked.

Comment: The tools won't scream at you, but the reason for the .h/.c convention is to ensure that every definition in your program exists only once in a single .c file. Including a .c file inside another duplicates its definitions and thus defeats the purpose. This would explain why C::B does not put your source directory into your include path by default.

Comment: Of course including a `.c` file works. If you know what you are doing it might be fine in rare cases, but in general it is confusing. If you add the file `vec2D.c` to the C::B project and include it in another `.c` file you will probably get the code compiled twice into both object files, probably creating conflicting symbols.

Comment: Maybe you should show your directory layout with your files and the contents of the C::B project file. Assuming you just started a project with a 2 files the project file should be relatively small.

Comment: alright, I created the header file for vec2d, #included that instead. The problem actually got worse, now it can't find vec2d.o either. It's also looking for "vec2d.h.gch" which did not get created either.

Comment: @Bodo, ok, posted an image. is it helpful?

Comment: @Introscopia Show the contents of the file `Space.cbp` formatted as code. You should move the definition of `struct vec2d` (and a prototype for function `add_vecs`) into `vec2d.h` and in `space.c` use `#include "vec2d.h"`

Comment: The problem appears to be the overall file structure and program design. You'll have to make sure to 1) put header guards in every single h file. 2) Always include h files never c files 3) Never define variables or functions in h files. 4) Ensure that each c file includes its corresponding h file 5) Ensure that all h files include other h files that they need to use 6) Ensure that no file includes nonsense files that do not exist in the same folder and project 7) Have a main() somewhere in a c file.

Comment: @Bodo done and done.

Comment: @Introscopia There seems to be something wrong. Your `.cbp` file contains only `<Unit filename="space.c">` while your image shows two source files and a header file. Did you save the project file?

Comment: @Bodo right, I had not. I did so and updated the xml in the post. the compiler throws the same errors.

Comment: Is the error message complete? Maybe there is a problem with the space in `C:/Users/Introscopia/Game Development/`. The error message doesn't seem to match your project. The message refers to a file `Development\Game\game.c` which is not listed in your project file.

Comment: it's complete as it appears in the log. I assume it has been shortened. There is no "Development" folder anywhere.

Comment: Did you try to rebuild the project after the changes? (Menu `Build` - `Rebuild`)

Comment: Yes. Same errors. But I've given up on CB and switched to command line. Thanks for trying!

Comment: It's hard to believe that you get an error message referring to a file `game.c` if your project contains only `space.c`, `vec2d.c` and `vec2d.h`. There seems to be a difference between your question and your actual project.

Comment: Like I explained in the post, one of the things I tried was re-creating the project with fresh files. That's when I changed the names.
Again, I've given up on CB, I'm doing just fine with my makefile now. Thank you!